# Hawaiian diacriticals

Tags: html, diacritics, abbr

Should you use an aria label within an abbreviation?

Example, UH is the abbreviation for University of Hawaiʻi. In locations where there is a use of diacritical marks, I am using an aria-label. But does it make sense to use the aria-label within the abbreviation? Or can I simply explain the abbreviation without the diacritical mark?

Combine the following:
`<span aria-label="Hawaii">Hawai&#699;i</span>`(with the diacritical mark)
and the abbreviation `<abbr title=“University of Hawaii”>UH</abbr>`

To make:

```
 <abbr title=“University of <span aria-label="Hawaii">Hawai&#699;i</span>”UH</abbr>
```

Or simplified?
`<abbr title=“University of Hawaii”>UH</abbr>` with no diacritical marks

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be a screen reader would read both of these items fine and you would not need an aria-label or anything else in this circumstance.

However, if you need to add text in markup attributes such as those used by aria then you will have to do the best you can without the diacritical mark. You could also investigate the use of `aria-labelledby` with an element otherwise not displayed or read out, but that would be over the top in my opinion.